# OpenERP Python object "Field date_start not found in browse_record(hr.contract, 56)"

Tags: python, module, odoo

I'm getting this error: `AttributeError: 'Field date_start not found in browse_record(hr.contract, 57)'`

But a field `date_start` really exists in the table `hr.contract`. This is a portion of the code:

```
def _iep_calc(self, cr, uid, ids, field, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for payslip in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        contrat = self.pool.get('hr.contract')
        for contrat_date_from in contrat.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
            date_f = contrat_date_from.date_start ## here is the problem
            date_t = datetime.date.today()
            DATETIME_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"
            from_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date_f), DATETIME_FORMAT)
            to_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date_t), DATETIME_FORMAT)
            timedelta = to_dt - from_dt
            diff_day = (timedelta.days + float(timedelta.seconds) / 86400) / 365
            res[payslip.id] = diff_day
    return res
```

Comment: What is `self` in this case? I mean which model is this method defined in? I have the feeling that you need to replace `ids` with something other in the line `... contrat.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):`. Of course, this is not an answer to your question but let start from somewhere. Indead, the `hr.contract` model has a `date_start` field...

Comment: First thanks for caring,the global idea ,i want to create a field in the table ***hr.payslip*** who stocke the number of years ,from the date in ***hr.contract.date_start*** to the current date,
the function made the necessary but i can't access to ***date_start***.
thanks